# Incorporating external jquery library

Tags: theming, 8, javascript

I am trying to use with Javascript in Drupal 8. I took an example from official drupal website, which I got it from https://www.drupal.org/project/examples and modified the code of ***js_example*** to incorporate **sDashboard** library.

The **js_example.libraries.yml** includes:

```
# A simple script using jquery ui accordion.
js_example.accordion:
  js:
    js/js_example_accordion.js: {}
  # Build up our dependencies for this page as a library. Our accordion script
  # needs jquery.ui.accordion. You can find the core scripts under core/assets/.
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery.ui.accordion
    - core/jquery

js_example.sdashboard:
  js:
    js/jquery-sDashboard.js : {}
  css:
    component:
      css/sDashboard.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui
    - core/jquery.datatables
```

The example module includes a Controller which I modified as:

```
public function getJsAccordionImplementation() {
    $title = t('Click sections to expand or collapse:');
    // Build using our theme. This gives us content, which is not a good
    // practice, but which allows us to demonstrate adding JavaScript here.
    $build['myelement'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'js_example_accordion',
      '#title' => $title,
    );
    // Add our script. It is tiny, but this demonstrates how to add it. We pass
    // our module name followed by the internal library name declared in
    // libraries yml file.
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'js_example/js_example.accordion';
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'js_example/js_example.sdashboard';
    // Return the renderable array.
    return $build;
  }
```

and there is an accordion.html.twig where I added the code for displaying the sdashboard widget. It is given as:

```
<div class="demo">
<h2>{{  title }}</h2>
<div id="accordion">
  .... accordion here ...
</div>
<ul id="myDashboard"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var tdata = [],i;

  for(i=0;i<4*Math.PI;i++){
  tdata.push([i,Math.sin(i)]);
  }

  var widgetDefinitions = [
  {   widgetTitle:"Plot Example",
      widgetId : "first" ,
      widgetType : "chart" , 
      widgetContent : {
      data : [tdata],
      options : {points:{show:true}}
      }

  }
  ]
  $("#myDashboard").sDashboard({
  dashboardData : widgetDefinitions
  });
</script>

</div>
```

Now when I am trying to run the example, I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
$("#myDashboard").sDashboard({
accordion (line 299, col 3)
ReferenceError: Flotr is not defined
factory($, Flotr);
```

Isn't this the usual way of using any external library in drupal. How do I use other libraries that I may need like sDashboard, etc?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add a js library from an external cdn in drupal 8 then, in your theme/module mycustom.libraries.yml file add do like this:

**NOTE:** Make sure you indent each spaces with two *spacebar press* button and not a tab press.

**NOTE:** *version* is optional here. You may not need add in.

```
mycustom.flexslider:
  version: 2.6.3
  css:
    theme:
      //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.css: {type: external}
  js:
    //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css: {type: external}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

If you are hosting it within your module or theme then:

**NOTE:** Here I placed flexslider within my theme or module vendor directory. So it would be inside mycustom/vendor/flexslider

```
mycustom.flexslider:
  version: 2.6.3
  css:
    theme:
      vendor/flexslider/flexslider.css: {}
  js:
    vendor/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

If you are just trying to host your custom js or css file then:

```
mycustom.myscript:
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
```

If its dependent on other library like core jquery or custom library then:

```
mycustom.myscript:
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/jquery
   - mycustom.myscript2
```

Then like in example module If I had to add flexslider library:

```
public function getFlexSliderImplementation() {

    $build['myelement'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'js_flexslider',
    );
    // Add our script. It is tiny, but this demonstrates how to add it. We pass
    // our module name followed by the internal library name declared in
    // libraries yml file.
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycustom/mycustom.flexslider';
    // Return the renderable array.
    return $build;
  }
```

**Update:**
Download and extract [Flotr2](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2) to your module or theme vendor directory. Modify libraries.yml file to include flotr2

```
js_example.flotr2:
 js:
   vendor/flotr2/flotr2.min.js : {}

js_example.sdashboard:
  css:
    component:
      vendor/sDashboard/sDashboard.css: {}
  js:
    vendor/sDashboard/jquery-sDashboard.js : {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui
    - core/jquery.datatables
    - js_example/js_example.flotr2
```

Comment: I have added the libraries in the libraries.yml file but I cannot use it on the program. I have done exactly like yours. Can you have a look into the code above if there is any mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Have you defined hook_theme to register your twig file with drupal in your .module file.

Comment: Yes i have used the example project from drupal which provided a sample js_example. It has made hook_theme implementation. I can see both sdashboard css and js loaded but still get the problem

Comment: You are using Flotr have you added in libraries.yml and defined it in your controller.

Comment: Yes. Can you take a look at my question above? I have mentioned the problem also. Thanks

Comment: Well I do not see [Flotr](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2) in your libraries.yml file. I see [sDashboard](https://github.com/ModelN/sDashboard) but you have not implemented Flotr. Include depenedent libraires as specified in sDashboard.

Comment: Well, it seems I missed putting `flotr`. I will update the code and let you know. Thanks for pointing me this.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know about it once I get it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48183/discussion-between-sarvagya-pant-and-sarathkm).